# Referencing one object function from another function within the same object

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get something like the following to work in JavaScript?

```
function a (){


  return{
    x: function foo(){
      ......
    }

    y: function bar(){
      .......
      .......
      foo()    //Doesn't work
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reference foo() inside the function bar() both of which happen to be inside the same return block?

Comment: The optional name for a function expression is only available within the function itself (except for certain buggy versions of IE).

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri— the property name *x* is not mapped to a variable name *x* in a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If*** `bar` will always/only be called as part of an expression looking it up on the object or in any other way that ensures `this` refers to the object during the call, e.g.:

```
theObject.y(); // Since you've called the property `y`
```

or

```
var b = theObject.y.bind(theObject);
b();
```

then you can use `this.x()` within `bar` to run `foo` (since you've used `x` rather than `foo` for the proprty name):

```js
function a() {
  return {
    x: function foo(){
      console.log("I'm foo");
    },

    y: function bar(){
      console.log("I'm bar, calling foo");
      this.x();
    }
  };
}

var obj = a();
obj.y();
```

When you do that, `this` will refer to the object within `foo` as well, which is handy if you need to refer to other object properties.

---

If `bar` may be called a different way, then you probably want to define the functions separately and then combine them in an object:

```
function a() {
  function foo(){
    // ......
  }

  function bar(){
    // .......
    // .......
    foo();
    // .....
  }

  return { x: foo, y: bar };
}
```

Example:

```js
function a() {
  function foo(){
    console.log("I'm foo");
  }

  function bar(){
    console.log("I'm bar, about to call foo");
    foo();
  }

  return { x: foo, y: bar };
}

var obj = a();
obj.y();
```

When `foo` is called this way, `this` will be `undefined` (in strict mode) or a reference to the global object (in loose mode), not a reference to the object; if you need a reference to the object, there are various ways to do that, such as assigning it to a variable that both `foo` and `bar` close over.